# How to implement Dependency Injection with MVC5 and MEF2 (Convention-Based) in an n-tier application?

Tags: dependency-injection, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern, mef2

I'm starting a new MVC project and have (almost) decided to give the Repository Pattern and Dependency Injection a go. It has taken a while to sift through the variations but I came up with the following structure for my application:

1. Presentation Layer: ASP.Net MVC front end (views/controllers, etc.)
2. Services Layer (Business Layer, if you prefer): interfaces and DTOs.
3. Data Layer: interface implementations and Entity Framework classes.

They are 3 separate projects in my solution. The Presentation Layer only has a reference to the Services Layer. The Data Layer also only has a reference to the Services Layer - so this is basically following Domain Driven Design.

The point of structuring things in this fashion is for separation of concerns, loose-coupling and testability. I'm happy to take advice on improvements if any of this is unreasonable?

The part I am having difficulty with is injecting an interface-implementing object from the Data Layer into the Presentation Layer, which is only aware of the interfaces in the Services Layer. This seems to be exactly what DI is for, and IoC frameworks (allegedly!) make this easier, so I thought I'd try MEF2. But of the dozens of articles and questions and answers I've read over the last few days, nothing seems to actually address this in a way that fits my structure. Almost all are deprecated and/or are simple console application examples that have all the interfaces and classes in the same assembly, knowing all about one another and entirely defying the point of loose-coupling and DI. I have also seen others that require the Data Layer dll being put in the presentation layer bin folder and configuring other classes to look there - again hampering the idea of loose-coupling.

There are some solutions that explore attribute-based registration, but that has supposedly been superseded by Convention-Based registration. I also see a lot of examples injecting an object into a controller constructor, which introduces it's own set of problems to solve. I'm not convinced the controller should know about this actually, and would rather have the object injected into the model, but there may be reasons for this as so many examples seem to follow that path. I haven't looked too deeply into this yet as I'm still stuck trying to get the Data Layer object up into the Presentation Layer anywhere at all.

I believe one of my main problems is not understanding in which layer the various MEF2 things need to go, since every example I've found only uses one layer. There are containers and registrations and catalogues and exporting and importing configurations, and I've been unable to figure out exactly where all this code should go.

The irony is that modern design patterns are supposed to abstract complexity and simplify our task, but I'd be half finished by now if I'd have just referenced the DAL from the PL and got to work on the actual functionality of the application. I'd really appreciate it if someone could say, 'Yep, I get what you're doing but you're missing xyz. What you need to do is abc'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've spent a couple more days on this (which is now around a week in total) and made little further progress. I am fairly sure I had the container set up correctly with my conventions discovering the correct parts to be mapped etc., but I couldn't figure out what seemed to be the missing link to get the controller DI to activate - I constantly received the error message stating that I hadn't provided a parameterless constructor. So I'm done with it.

I did, however, manage to move forward with my structure and intention to use DI with an IoC. If anyone hits the same wall I did and wants an alternative solution: ditch MEF 2 and go with Unity. The latest version (3.5 at time of writing) has discovery by convention baked in and just works like a treat out of the box - it even has a fairly thorough manual with worked examples. There are other IoC frameworks, but I chose Unity since it's MS supported and fares well in performance benchmarks. Install the bootstrapper package from NuGet and most of the work is done for you. In the end I only had to write one line of code to map my entire DAL (they even create a stub for you so you know where to insert it):

```
        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(t => t.Namespace == "xxx.DAL.Repository"),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I get what you're doing (more or less) but (as far as I can tell) you're missing a) the separation of contracts and implementation types into their own projects/assemblies and b) a concept for configuring the DI-container, i.e. configure which implementations shall be used for the interfaces.

There are unlimited ways of dealing with this, so what I give you is my personal best practice. I've been working that way for quite a bit now and am still happy with it, so I consider it worth sharing.

**a. Always have to projects: `MyNamespace.Something` and `MyNamespace.Something.Contracts`**

In general, for DI, I have two assemblies: One for contracts which holds only interfaces and one for the implementation of these interfaces. In your case, I would probably have five assemblies: `Presentation.dll`, `Services.dll`, `Services.Contracts.dll`, `DataAccess.dll` and `DataAccess.Contracts.dll`.

(Another valid option is to put all contracts in one assembly, lets call it Commons.dll)

Obviously, `DataAccess.dll` references `DataAccess.Contracts.dll`, as the classes inside `DataAccess.dll` implement the interfaces inside `DataAccess.Contracts.dll`. Same for `Services.dll` and `Services.Contracts.dll`.

No, the decoupling part: `Presentation` references `Services.Contracts` and `Data.Contracts`. Services references `Data.Contracts`. As you see, there is no dependency to concrete implementations. This is, what the whole DI thing is about. If you decide to exchange your data access layer, you can swap `DataAccess.dll` while `DataAccess.Contracts.dll` stays the same. None of your othe assemblies reference DataAccess.dll directly, so there are no broken links, version conflicts, etc. If this is not clear, try to draw a little dependency diagram. You will see, that there are no arrows pointing to any assemblies whioch don't have `.Contracts` in their name.

Does this make sense to you? Please ask, if there is something unclear.

**b. Choose how to configure the container**

You can choose between explicit configuration (XML, etc.), attribute based configuration and convention based registration. While the former is a pain for obvious reasons, I am a fan of the second. I think it is more readable and easy to debug than convention based config, but that is a matter of taste.

Of course, the container kind of bundles all the dependencies, which you have spared in your application architecture. To make clear what I mean, consider a XML config for your case: It will contain 'links' to all of the implementation assemblies `DataAccess.dll, ...`. Still, this doesn't undermine the idea of decoupling. It is clear, that you need to modify the configuration, when an implementation assembly is exchanged.

However, working with attribute or convention based configs, you generally work with the autodiscovery mechanisms you mention: 'Search in all assemblies located in xyz'. This does require to place all assemblies in the applications *bin* directory. There is nothing wrong about it, as the code needs to be somewhere, right?

What do you gain? Consider you've deployed your application and decide to swap the DataAccess layer. Say, you've chosen convention based config of your DI container. What you can do now is to open a new project in VS, reference the existing `DataAccess.Contracts.dll` and implement all the interfaces in whatever way you like, as long as you follow the conventions. Then you build the library, call it `DataAccess.dll` and copy and paste it to your original application's program folder, replacing the old `DataAccess.dll`. Done, you've swapped the whole implementation without any of the other assemblies even noticing.

I think, you get the idea. It really is a tradeoff, using IoC and DI. I highly recommend to be pragmatic in your design decisions. Don't interface everything, it just gets messy. Decide for yourself, where DI and IoC really makes sense and don't get too influenced by the community's religious discussions. Still, used wisely, IoC and DI are really, really, really powerful!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Marc. Your first point is something I have actually covered, although a little differently to you. My interfaces (contracts) are in the BL, separate to the implementation in the DAL. The only dependencies are on the interfaces (contracts). Your second point is quite correct, however - I lack a clear vision of how to configure the DI container. Knowing that I need to put the data.dll in the app bin gives me something to go on. It is difficult to filter out the deprecated techniques (eg. controller factories) and find clear examples of what to do though. I'll persist!